# Can I use Catch with boost/program_options.hpp?

Tags: boost-program-options, catch-unit-test

I have a program that uses boost/program_options.hpp to process command line arguments. I want to add unit-tests to this program, and the [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) framework is very attractive. However, it seems to mess with the command line arguments to my program.

How can I use Catch and still have boost/program_options.hpp process the command line arguments?

And if boost/program_options.hpp is processing the options to my program, how can I configure Catch?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check the following link:

https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/own-main.md

I believe you have to supply your own main and control your command line arguments with the boost/program_options.hpp